# How to sign in a user with AWS Amplify on Android + Kotlin?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make an Android app with a sign in screen on Android in Kotlin using AWS Amplify, here's my sign in code:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password, null, object : Callback<SignInResult> {

        override fun onResult(signInResult: SignInResult) {
            runOnUiThread {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Sign-in callback state: " + signInResult.signInState)
                when (signInResult.signInState) {
                    SignInState.DONE -> Log.d("DEBUG", "Sign-in done.")
                    SignInState.SMS_MFA -> Log.d("DEBUG", "Please confirm sign-in with SMS.")
                    SignInState.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED -> Log.d("DEBUG", "Please confirm sign-in with new password.")
                    else -> Log.d("DEBUG", "Unsupported sign-in confirmation: " + signInResult.signInState)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "Sign-in error", e)
        }
    })
```

I used the documentation of Amazon [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication), copied and pasted the block found at the Sign In chapter into Android Studio that automatically converted the Java code into Kotlin.

Using logs I see that my code above this one is executed when I press the login button but the `onResult` block is never called. The logs only print a `D/AWSMobileClient: Sending password.` from AWS sdk.

I remember that this code worked before Christmas holidays so I think that it's maybe a change on the Amazon side but I find nothing in the documentation.

Do you have any idea of what's wrong here ?

Comment: Can you share your logs and any stacktraces? That will be helpful to debug this further.

Comment: @Bommas sure, I'll post that when back home and thank's for your answer

Comment: @Bommas Well... I got an error on my iOS version of the app so I recreated my Cognito user pool and now it works on both sides, including Android. Conclusion: problem solved by deleting and recreating my Cognito user pool. Thank's for your time

Comment: glad that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Got the problem again, actually I just need to restart the emulator